# How do I scan JSON with jquery to determine the number of instances of a certain string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON which looks generally like this...

```
{"appJSON": [
{
"title":"Application Title",
"category":"Business", 
"industry":"Retail", 
"language":"English", 
"tags":[
        {"tags":"Sales"},{"tags":"Reporting"},{"tags":"Transportation"},{"tags":"Hospitality"}
       ], 
},
{
"title":"Airline Quality Assurance",
...
...
...]}
```

I'm looping through JSON to get an array of all of the unique Tags in the data.

My question is, now that I have an array of the different unique Tags in the JSON, how do I best determine the number of times each Tag occurs?

So basically I'm looking to generate a list of all of the tags found in the JSON (which I already have) with the number of times each one occurs (which I don't already have).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Lemme guess.. tag cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming when you find a new tag you check to see if you already have that tag somewhere.  If you don't you add it to your list.  Why not when you check do something like.

```
var nextTag=//get the next tag in the JSON list
var newTag=true;
for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
  if(nextTag === tags[i]){
    tagCount[i]++;
    newTag=false;
    break;
  }
}
if(newTag){
  tags[tags.length]=nextTag;
  tagCount[tagCount.length]=1;
}
```

This uses two arrays where `tagCount[i]` is the number of times tag in `tags[i]` occurs.  You could uses an object to do this or however you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, here's a function which will fill an associative array; the keys will be the tags and the values will be the number of occurrences of that tag.

```
var tagCounts = []; // Global variable here, but could be an object property or any array you like really

function countTags(tags, tagCounts)
{
    $.each(tags, function(i, item) {

        var tag = item.tags; // This would change depending on the format of your JSON

        if(tagCounts[tag] == undefined) // If there's not an index for this tag
            tagCounts[tag] = 0;

        tagCounts[tag]++;

    });
}
```

So you can call this function on any number of arrays of tags, passing in your tagCounts (totals) array, and it will aggregate the totals.

```
var tags1 = [{"tags":"Sales"},{"tags":"Reporting"},{"tags":"Transportation"},{"tags":"Hospitality"}];
var tags2 = [{"tags":"Reporting"},{"tags":"Transportation"}];
var tags3 = [{"tags":"Reporting"},{"tags":"Hospitality"}];

countTags(tags1, tagCounts);
countTags(tags2, tagCounts);
countTags(tags3, tagCounts);
```

Then you can read them out like so:

```
for(var t in tagCounts)
    // t will be the tag, tagCounts[t] will be the number of occurrences
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/UVUrJ/1/

qw3n's answer is actually a more efficient way of doing things, as you're only looping through all the tags once—but unless you have a really huge JSON source the difference isn't going to be noticeable.